# ASP.NET MVC 4 - Is there a way to shorten URLs?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Is there a way using routes in mvc to shorten the url? I'm fairly new to MVC, and I guess I don't quite yet understand what `routes.IgnoreRoute()`does fully.

So for the sake of example, using routes could I make this,

site.com/webFolder/controller/action

look like,

site.com/controller?

Also if it helps we're currently using IIS7. Thx all.

Comment: then you will need only one action per controller ?

Comment: hm. no.. controllers have 2 actions.

Comment: site.com/controller how do you want to call action?

Comment: i guess that's where my knowledge gap is. what i would like to display is 'site.com/controller', and was initially curious if having `Response.Redirect("action");` throughout my code would accommodate the calling of actions.

Comment: if you configure your route site.com/controller then you do not have chance to call different actions ,only one default action called that is specified in routeconfig

Comment: @ConvertToInt32 would you have any suggestions as to how i could shorten this up some?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create custom routes. Take a look at this:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-custom-routes-cs

In the example given a route of /Archive/{entryDate} was created using

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Blog",                                           // Route name
            "Archive/{entryDate}",                            // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Archive", action = "Entry" }  // Parameter defaults
        );
```